# peewee.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter while saving big amout of data

Tags: python, database, orm, zip, peewee

I create many records in my DB as follows:

`Subproducts.create(mf_id=mf_id,
                     co=co,
                     mf_binary=mf_binary_data.getbuffer())`

`mf_binary` type is `io.BytesIO()` - it is binary representation of binary files collected into zipfile

I've successfully created many records using this approach, however I have an issue with one particular dataset. 
It is a bigger than other and it takes ~1,2GB. 
When I try to save it in DB following error occurs.
`peewee.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.`

Field of mf_binary in my model is `peewee.BlobField(default=b'0')`

How can I store this kind of data in peewee Database?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getbuffer()` returns a `memoryview` object which is apparently not supported by the underlying database driver (which one is it, by the way?). The `InterfaceError` is raised by your database driver as opposed to Peewee, which indicates the problem comes from your driver not understanding how to handle `memoryview` objects.

Your best bet is to use `mf_binary_data.getvalue()`, which should return a `bytes` object.

Comment: I use Sqlite driver. I tried to use `getvalue()` instead of `getbuffer()`, but it does not help. I have no issues with other datasets. I can store them in DB and extract them to the files. But I have one datasets which cause problems, probably because of size. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: "but it does not help" -- surely you're not receiving the same error just trying to insert a bytestring?